# Visual C# .NET Messagebox

Tags: c#

My question is can we write:

```
String s="Sarath";
MessageBox.Show("My Name is Sarath {0}",s);
```

I want to get the name at the {0}.....
Is there any way...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx) for that ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
string myName = "Sarath";
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("My name is {0}.", myName));
```